# How to create feeds for JSON input in Kylo?

Tags: json, feed, kylo

How to create feeds for JSON input in Kylo? I get error while creating Advanced Ingest with JSON sample file

> An error occurred Unexpected exception. Verify file is the proper format for all valid json files.

Please share the suggestion to create JSON to Hive feed in Kylo?

Answer (score 1):

There are many causes of this error so I'll highlight the most common:

A) Kylo is expecting a file that contains one JSON dictionary per line. It won't work with a multiline JSON document or with an array of JSON documents. Kylo provides a couple examples to help you get started: https://github.com/Teradata/kylo/tree/master/samples/sample-data/json

B) If the examples aren't working then it's likely that Kylo is unable to start a Spark job to analyze the file schema. Please check the /var/log/kylo/kylo-services.log and /var/log/kylo/kylo-spark-shell.log files for errors.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I get same error while using example JSON data mentioned in the link. Can you share the commands how to check the logs in kylo, since I don’t find any file in VM?
**[root@sandbox ~]# ls
anaconda-ks.cfg original-ks.cfg**
I couldn’t find the logs mentioned in the 2nd point.

Comment: I look at the logs using `less /var/log/kylo-services/kylo-services.log`. You can also copy them to your host machine using `scp -p 2222 root@localhost:/var/log/kylo-services/kylo-services.log .`